# How to filter the array that contains objects with gaps key init

Tags: javascript

```
const cards = [
        {gaps: ["science", "education"]},
        {gaps: ["weapon"]},
        {gaps: ["figures", "character"]},
        {gaps: ["figures", "education"]},
      ]

function filter({})
```

Please help, there is an array
when calling filter ()
this should return 5 groups into the console

1. {gaps: ["science", "education"]} - science
2. {gaps: ["science", "e`enter code here`ducation"]}, {gaps: ["figures", "education"]} - education
3. {gaps: ["weapon"]} - weapon
4. {gaps: ["figures", "character"]}, ["figures", "education"]} - figures
5. {gaps: ["figures", "character"]} - character

Comment: Any time you want to go from ``n` number of items to `m` number of items, where `m` isn't a subset of `n`, you want to use `reduce()`, not `filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over `cards` while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the `key` is the gap and the `value` is the list of objects having this gap in its gaps array.

In each iteration, you would iterate over the `gaps` using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and update the Map:

```js
const cards = [ {gaps: ["science", "education"]}, {gaps: ["weapon"]}, {gaps: ["figures", "character"]}, {gaps: ["figures", "education"]} ];

const gapsMap = cards.reduce((map, { gaps = [] }) => {
  gaps.forEach(gap => map.set(gap, [...(map.get(gap) || []), {gaps: [...gaps]}]));
  return map;
}, new Map);

console.log([...gapsMap]);
console.log(gapsMap.get("education"));
```